# Updating individual values (not rows) in an R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to update values of `var3` in an R data.frame `mydata` according to a simple criterion.

```
   var1  var2  var3
1  1     4     5
2  3     58    800
3  8     232   8
```

I would think that the following should do:

```
mydata$var3[mydata$var3 > 500,] <- NA
```

However, this replaces the entire row of every matching record with NA (all cells of the row), instead of just the `var3` value (cell):

```
   var1  var2  var3
1  1     4     5
2  NA    NA    NA
3  8     232   8
```

How can I ensure that just the value for the selected variable is replaced? `mydata` should then look like

```
   var1  var2  var3
1  1     4     5
2  3     58    NA
3  8     232   8
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `which` and `arr.ind=TRUE`

```
> mydata[which(mydata[,3]>500, arr.ind=TRUE), 3] <- NA
> mydata
  var1 var2 var3
1    1    4    5
2    3   58   NA
3    8  232    8
```

Or just modify your previous attempt...

```
mydata[mydata$var3 > 500, 3] <- NA
```

This also works

```
mydata$var3[mydata$var3 > 500 ] <- NA   # note no comma is inside [ ]
```

Your attempt didnt work because `mydata$var3` gives a vector and you are indexing it as if it were a matrix by using `[mydata$var3 > 500,]` so a dimension error is thrown. You almost got it, all you have to do is remove the comma in your code (see my last alternative).

Comment: Thanks! Why couldn't I use `mydata[mydata$var3 > 500, c('var3')] <- NA` then?

Comment: `mydata[mydata$var3 > 500, c('var3')] <- NA` works fine for me.

Comment: @sam make sure you've not got back-ticks " ` "  as opposed to " ' " surrounding `var3` in there

Comment: Thanks, but that's really not the problem... I'm using `model.data$var3[model.data$var3 > 500] <- NA`, which results in rows such as `NA.2  NA  NA  NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA` – This is absolutely weird.

Comment: I'm so sorry everyone; I simply used the wrong command to actually visualize the rows (`mydata[mydata$var3 > 500,]`) – it's all fine now...

Comment: Glad your problem is solved @sam, now you can upvote the answer and accept it as correct ;)